# Triple Displays with Ivy Bridge Ultrabooks

Tags: external-display, ivy-bridge

It was advertised over and over again that the **mobile** and **desktop** version of the Ivy Bridge intel processors would support up to three independent displays (external-external-external or internal-external-external).  Are there any notebooks on the market that support this setup?  I know Intel said there will be this fall, but I haven't found any yet.

Comment: To my knowledge there's nothing on the market yet...the chipset supports it but nobody is actually implementing it yet.  This is true on desktops as well, you could very easily make a board that supports three simultaneous outputs but nobody's bothered (perhaps because two of them have to be DisplayPort?)  I'm not making this an answer because I haven't revisited this since a conversation about it with our Intel rep, which was probably in like June.

Comment: @Shinrai you get an upvote anyways for offering useful information.

I thought about buying one of the sony i7 ivy bridge laptops but could not get a solid answer on the web or through a salesperson if they supported dual external, let alone triple.

Comment: FWIW, USB video solutions are robust enough now that if you don't need any significant rendering performance that they work just fine to add outputs.  (There are some high end Quadro and Firepro chips in current-gen laptops that do up to five outputs via docking station but it sounds like you're not looking to spend that much.)